# Is there any alternative of Newsapi for react-native

Tags: api, react-native

I am building news app I want to use api  other than 'newsapi'. Is there any alternative for the same?

Answer (score 1):

- **webhose**

They provide free trial which allows 1,000 requests per month and you have to subscribe for additional requests and they also have pay as you go feature.

https://webhose.io/

- **New York Times API**

New York Times API provide 4,000 free requests per day and it's versatile and has geographically linked data, live news feed, etc.

https://developer.nytimes.com

Answer (score 0):

There are some open APIs for news you need to check:

Currents = Latest news published in various news sources, blogs and forums
https://currentsapi.services/en

The Guardian = Access all the content the Guardian creates, categorised by tags and section
https://open-platform.theguardian.com/

NPR One = Personalized news listening experience from NPR
https://dev.npr.org/api/

You might need to sign up for an authentication key, and it'll work!